# The rides are dangerous to the teenagers {to play/playing} there

Tags: difference, infinitive-vs-gerund, infinitive-clauses

- The rides are dangerous to the teenagers **to play** there.
- The rides are dangerous to the teenagers **playing** there.

Are both acceptable expressions? Is there any difference in meaning between the two sentences, that is, the difference between to infinitive and present participle?

Is the difference in meaning similar to the difference between "the teenagers who will play there" (to infinitive) and "the teenagers who are playing there (present participle)"?

Comment: Please note: to the teenagers is not a to-infinitive. It is a prepositional phrase. The first is not grammatical. Also, your first examples are not like your last comment where you ask what the difference is between them.

Comment: Note also that dangerous to... is usually followed by a verb. The person risking the danger is usually specified with **for**, for example "dangerous for the teenagers". Plus, playing is something that children do: many teenagers would resent any suggestion that they are 'playing'.

Comment: Note, change "teenagers *to* play there" to "teenagers *who* play there" and it would be ok (aside from changing the first "to" to "for")

Answer (score 2):

*Dangerous* takes the following frames:

> 1. *Something* is dangerous [to/for *somebody*].

Examples:

- Smoking is dangerous.
- Plastic bags are dangerous for small children.
- Those rides are dangerous for teenagers.

> 2. *Something* is dangerous [for *somebody*] to *infinitive clause*.

Examples:

- Gunpowder is dangerous to play with.
- Magic words are dangerous to speak.
- Building sites are dangerous for children to play in.

But note that if there is an infinitive clause, it must relate to the *something*, either taking it as a direct object (the middle example above) or as an indirect object with a preposition such as *on* or *with*. A clause unconnected with the "something" doesn't make sense:

- ?Gunpowder is dangerous to paint the wall.

> 3. It is dangerous [ for *somebody*] to *infinitive clause*.

Examples:

- It is dangerous to drink and drive.
- It is dangerous for teenagers to play in that park.

Since there isn't a "something", there is not the same restriction on the infinitive clause.

So your second sentence works (though I would use *for* rather than *to*):

> The rides are dangerous to the teenagers playing there.

because "playing there" is not an infinitive clause relating to "dangerous", but a participial clause modifying "the teenagers". It groups as "The rides are dangerous to [the teenagers playing there]".

But your first sentence doesn't work. "to play there" does not attach either to "the teenagers" or to "dangerous".